# #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails on my table

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I Have 2 tables which is departements and students with this schema on my foreign key

```
departements.id = students.departement_id
```

i tried to delete one of my departement.id but it returns an error with this

```
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`u1556075_sia_uiii2`.`#sql-f847_33d3d1a`, CONSTRAINT `departements_fk2` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `students` (`departement_id`)
```

honestly idk what makes this happen because my foreign key on student is just like this

```
ALTER TABLE `students` ADD CONSTRAINT `students_fk2` FOREIGN KEY (`departement_id`) REFERENCES `departements`(`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```

Comment: Please add your full table definitions as text.

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete a row in `departments` if there is one or more rows in `students` referencing that row's department id. The reason is that if you were to delete the row in `departments`, then some rows in `students` would reference a department id that no longer exists in the database, which would be a violation of the foreign key constraint.

You must first UPDATE the `students` table to change the department id on rows that match the department you want to delete. Either change those students to some other department, or else set the department_id to NULL. Or I suppose it would also work to delete the rows in `students`, but I assume you don't want to do that.

Comment: Yeah i assume just like you, but on the real case, there are no ```departement.id``` which has the same in my ```students.departement_id``` and thats what i confuse about